# Error when trying to get Chromium source code (Value from deps_os...)

Tags: browser, open-source, chromium

I am trying to get the source code of Chromium 34, so I followed the instructions on Chromium.org:
http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code/working-with-release-branches
On the last command, `gclient sync --with_branch_heads --jobs 16`, I get an error saying "Error: 1> Value from deps_os (...)."

Full Error:

```
gclient(569) MergeWithOsDeps:Ignoring 'src/pdf':None in 'android' deps_os
gclient(569) MergeWithOsDeps:Ignoring 'src/chrome/test/data/perf/canvas_bench':None in 'ios' deps_os
gclient(569) MergeWithOsDeps:Ignoring 'src/chrome/test/data/perf/frame_rate/content':None in 'ios' deps_os
gclient(569) MergeWithOsDeps:Ignoring 'src/native_client':None in 'ios' deps_os
gclient(569) MergeWithOsDeps:Ignoring 'src/third_party/ffmpeg':None in 'ios' deps_os
gclient(569) MergeWithOsDeps:Ignoring 'src/third_party/hunspell':None in 'ios' deps_os
gclient(569) MergeWithOsDeps:Ignoring 'src/third_party/hunspell_dictionaries':None in 'ios' deps_os
gclient(569) MergeWithOsDeps:Ignoring 'src/third_party/webgl':None in 'ios' deps_os
Syncing projects: 100% ( 1/ 1) src

src (ERROR)
----------------------------------------
[0:00:00] Started.
[0:00:00] ________ unmanaged solution; skipping src
----------------------------------------
Error: 1> Value from deps_os ('ios'; 'src/tools/gyp': {'url': 'https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/gyp.git@fe00999dfaee449d3465a9316778434884da4fa7', 'should_process': False}) conflicts with existing deps entry ({'url': 'https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/gyp.git@82b08049cc0b1f9e0bdcc0702ac6b523360f635f'}).
```